# Run Xamarin project from command line

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I have a C# project on OSX that I built and execute through Xamarin. How can I run this project from the command line? What parameters do I need to pass to `mono`?

Comment: How come you are not using `MSBuild`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While my Xamarin project was originally building an OSX app instead of a standalone mono executable, it is possible first to build a seperate executable and run that with mono.

For me this involved running `mcs` (the mono compiler) with every source file and every DLL used by my Xamarin project. Most of my source files were in a single directory, and Xamarin kindly gathers all your DLLs in a directory for you under `./bin/Debug/XXXXXXXXXXX.app/Contents/MonoBundle/`. I took all these DLLs, moved them to a new directory `lib`. Then I could compile my project like this:

```
mcs *.cs -r:lib/MonoMac.dll -r:lib/MoreLinq.dll -r:lib/OpenTK.dll
```

This will output a mono executable with the name of the first source file. It can be run by copying the file into the `lib` directory and running it there:

```
cp Program.exe lib
cd lib
mono Program.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

## Basic usage

The normal way to run an application you have compiled with Mono would be to invoke it through the Mono runtime, like this:

```
mono myprogram.exe
```

Ref: The **highly** outdated doc page @ http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/

So, in the most basic form, you only need to pass your CIL-based `.exe` to the `mono` runtime/executable. For *advanced* needs, consult the `man` page for mono for additional options:

`man mono`

```
NAME
       mono  -  Mono's ECMA-CLI native code generator (Just-in-Time and Ahead-of-
       Time)

SYNOPSIS
       mono [options] file [arguments...]

       mono-sgen [options] file [arguments...]
~~~~~~
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I just run `mono myprogram.exe` I get the following error: `No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting`

Comment: What type of project are you building/running? If you are trying to run a Xamarin.Mac project from the cmd line, you would need to `open MyMonoMac.app`, if this is an iOS project, you can not 'run' it from cmd-line, you would either need to run it from within the iOS Simulator or install it on a iOS device...

Comment: It is a Mac project, and in fact, it does run when called from `open`, however I'm hoping there's a way to run the project by calling `mono` directly. The end goal is to enable profiling.